# How to render a variable in a django template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

My goal is to write dynamically some urls of images in the HTML page. Urls are stored in a database.

To do so, first I am trying to render a simple varable in a template.  Reading the docs and other sources, it should be done in 3 steps:

For the configuration: **in settings.py**

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'OPTIONS': {
        'debug': DEBUG,
        'context_processors': [
            …
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
            'django.template.context_processors.media',
            'django.template.context_processors.static',
            'django.template.context_processors.tz',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',            ],
    },
},
```

]

The variable name **in the template: In MyHTMLFile.html** is foo

```
…
<td>MyLabel</td><td><p>{{ foo }}</p></td><td>-----------</td>
…
```

**in the view.py**, one of the lines

```
myvar1 ="BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB"
context = {foo: myvar1,}

return render_to_response("MyHTMLFile.html", context, context_instance = RequestContext(request) )
return render(request, 'MyHTMLFile.html', {foo: myvar1})
return render_to_response("MyHTMLFile.html", context , context_instance=RequestContext(request) )
return render(request, 'MyHTMLFile.html', context)
```

The html page is well rendered, but no data in the html table.

Do you have an idea ? I am curious to know what i misunderstand.

Regarding the versio, i am using: 
python: Python 2.7.13
django: 1.10.5

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
context = {foo: myvar1,}
```

This should give you a `NameError` unless ofcourse you have a variable named `foo` in which case it may or may not hold a string `foo`. So in short you are not sending the right data to the template. It should be

```
context = {'foo': myvar1,}
```

And then

```
return render_to_response("MyHTMLFile.html", context, context_instance = RequestContext(request) )
# Below this line code will not be executed.
return render(request, 'MyHTMLFile.html', {foo: myvar1})
return render_to_response("MyHTMLFile.html", context , context_instance=RequestContext(request) )
return render(request, 'MyHTMLFile.html', context)
```

note that the `return` keyword **returns** from the function. Code after that doesn't get executed.

lastly render_to_response is deprecated. `render` is the current function to use.

Comment: Thank you e4c5. Your 2 remarks are pertinents and i correct my code. I solved my problem because thank to you i realize i was doing the bad test. So doing the right test and your 2 code adjustements it works as expected.

Comment: I tried to upvote...but there was a message in red "You can accept the answer in 3 minutes" :-)

Comment: Ah now worries. All the best with your project