# How are my html templates able to get the username without any arguments passed by views.py?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, google-authentication

I have a djongo engine based google authentication applications

My views.py renders the homepage, without passing any arguments:

```
return render(request=request,template_name="mainapp/homepage.html")
```

And homepage.html looks like:

```html
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body bgcolor = "green">
       <p>THIS IS THE HOMEPAGE</p>
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
             <p class="display-4">Hello, {{ user.username }} you are signed in</p>
             <a href="/account/logout">Log out</a>
        {% else %}
            <a href={% url "social:begin" "google-oauth2" %}>Login with Google</a>
            <p>Not signed in</p>
 {% endif %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Yet after the user logs in it shows the correct username( not that of the admin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because of [**`django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/api/#django-contrib-auth-context-processors-auth) context processor from your settings:

```
'OPTIONS': {
    'context_processors': [
        'django.template.context_processors.debug',
        'django.template.context_processors.request',
        'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth', 
        'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        'django.template.context_processors.media',
    ],
```

It attaches the current logged in user in Template. As per documentation:

> if this processor is enabled, every RequestContext will contain these
>   variables:
>
> - user – An auth.User instance representing the currently logged-in user (or an AnonymousUser instance, if the client isn’t logged in).
> - perms – An instance of django.contrib.auth.context_processors.PermWrapper, representing the
>     permissions that the currently logged-in user has.

You can checkout it's [**`source`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/contrib/auth/context_processors/#auth) as well.

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to display extra things in your view, pass those values in `context`.

```py
return render(request=request,template_name="mainapp/homepage.html", context = {user: request.user})
```

But if the user is not logged-in you will get a empty string when accessing `user.username`. Because an [AnonymousUser object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/auth/#anonymoususer-object)'s username is always returns the empty string.

You can learn more things like pass extra values to you template from this question -->
[How to render a variable in a django template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44415794/how-to-render-a-variable-in-a-django-template)

- But if you want to do this by without passing anything in `context`, just add below solution into you template.

`{{ request.user.username }}`

You can access anything in `request object` like that. For more information check this question --> [What does request.user refer to in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17312831/what-does-request-user-refer-to-in-django)

Comment: Yes, but how are the templates able to access the username without views.py passing any user arguments to the templates

Comment: @VrukshaNikam try this, `{{ request.user.username }}` without passing `context`.